# Animation makes element go out of screen

Tags: javascript, if-statement, animation

[Video showing the problem.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v6LZ-Bvr1jBmwdOFkHt5QGwYpAR7dTA3/view)
Im making JavaScript project about horse race game, and on race track there are obstacles that character should detect and trigger the animation of jumping.  For no obvious reason, the animation is triggering in bad way and the character fly out of the screen, after a while it's returning and same thing occurs at second obstacle. In the beggining of the video im just showing how the animation should look like.

The logic is build about *setInterval* and function with *element.offsetTop*. 
Start button triggers the interval which triggers function of moving. Inside that function, the position of the character and currently selected (by *i* counter) obstacle are checked. When the character gets 80 pixels before obstacle, if-statement triggers the animation by adding class name to element, and after that I have no idea what is happening. Instead of imitating Daedalus it should perform the animation smoothly, trigger another if-statement to count the bush and remove the given class name to make another jump viable.

The CSS code of animation

```
.horse.jump {
animation-iteration-count: 500;
transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1,1);
margin-top: 0;
animation-direction: initial, initial;
background-position:48px -192px;
animation-fill-mode: backwards;
animation: jump 1s;
}
```

The JS code

```
var horse = document.getElementsByClassName('horse');
var bush = document.getElementsByClassName('bush');    
var i = 0; //Counter for the next obstacle    

function horseMoving () { 
    //Function connecting Start Button with 
    // moving function by interval
    setInterval(moveDown, 9);
}

function moveDown (){   
    // Cheking character position   
    var positionHorseUp = horse[0].offsetTop;

    //Checking for the current closest obstacle
    var positionBushUp = bush[i].offsetTop;

    horse[0].classList.add('runDown');      
    horse[0].style.top = positionHorseUp + 1 + 'px';

    //When the character gets close to obstacle
    if (positionHorseUp==positionBushUp-80) {

        //Makes horse to jump
        horse[0].classList.add('jump');         
    }   

   //When the character gets away from obstacle
    if (positionHorseUp==positionBushUp+20) {           
        //Takes away the jump class
        horse[0].classList.remove('jump');

        // This statements prevents an array 
        // from getting out of elements 
        // and triggers cheking for next obstacle
        if (i<5) { 
            i++; }  
    }   
}

 // These 2 functions are only for video purpose
function showJump() {
    horse[0].classList.add('jump')}
function showJump2() {
    horse[0].classList.remove('jump')}


function loadFunction() {

    var startButton = document.getElementById('start')
    startButton.addEventListener('click', horseMoving)

    // These 2 lines are only for video purpose
    startButton.addEventListener('click', showJump2)
    horse[0].addEventListener('click', showJump)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loadFunction);
```

Comment: Still can't solve this problem, I tried tracking how many times the if-statement triggers but I doesn't solved anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have an animation applied to the `jump` class, the `offsetTop` value is actually altered when that class is added. Thus, you shouldn't depend on `offsetTop`, and rather you should use an independent variable that you set yourself, having the `offsetTop` depend on *it*. Set it to the `offsetTop` initially, but then increment it instead of incrementing the `offsetTop`, and then set the `top` to it. That's probably confusing, so let me post some code.

You'd add this around the start of your script.

```
var positionHorseUp;
```

Then this to your load event.

```
positionHorseUp = horse[0].offsetTop;
```

Then you'd remove this line...

```
var positionHorseUp = horse[0].offsetTop;
```

...and replace the one that sets the `top` position with this one.

```
horse[0].style.top = ++positionHorseUp + 'px';
```

That way, nothing depends on the `offsetTop` value and you can safely apply that animation without it interrupting the stored position of the horse.

(Also, use [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame), not `setTimeout`. It's more efficient because it is called on every paint frame. Add respective code as well to compensate for the indefinite time intervals between browser environments.)

Comment: Thanks for help. Best streamer of all coders and best coder of all streamers.